# Does it make sense to have more shards than physical servers to spread Mongo writes?

Tags: mongodb, replication, scaling, sharding

MongoDB uses master-slave replication, which means that all writes go to the single master node (slaves are just backups or standby, or can serve reads that need not be absolutely current).

MongoDB also has sharding which splits the data into shards, each of which has their own replication set (i.e. their own master). As a result, if writes are spread evenly across shards, write performance increases.

So far, I have only considered sharding as a scale-out option: Add more machines to host the shards.

Does it make sense to have multiple shards on the same machine just to spread out writes, too?

```
Machine A:   [Shard A Master] [Shard B Replica]
Machine B:   [Shard B Master] [Shard C Replica]
Machine C:   [Shard C Master] [Shard A Replica]
```

Comment: I just watched the sharding and replication videos on the mongodb site 2 nights ago. Really great information. This sounds just like a RAID5 configuration of drives, where each drive contains parity information for the others. I would be interested to know as well if this has any benefits.

Comment: My hunch is that it is probably not a good idea, as it would reduce reduce the RAM available to the master. Mongo likes RAM.

Comment: Though if there were plenty of ram in the system, then maybe it wouldn't matter?

Comment: slightly OT but: better to use raid 6 (which is raid 5 plus a spare disk which is like few hundred $). just had a raid 5 setup degrade and Linux going to a read-only mode, not good for a production setup :)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, running multiple `mongod` processes per physical machine (either as a replica set or as shard servers for different shards) does not increase write performance compared to running a single `mongod` per machine. MongoDB will perform very well under concurrent write scenarios as long as the "working set" of data (that is, frequently-accessed data) and indexes fits within RAM -- if you have only one `mongod` per machine, that `mongod` has access to all of RAM; if you have more, they will eventually contend with one another for a limited resource.

In special circumstances, such as if you have a lot of excess capacity on your physical machines, running multiple `mongod`s can be beneficial, as they can better take advantage of the resources available on the machine.

Comment: "MongoDB will perform very well under concurrent write scenarios". Are there any benchmarks of what throughput to expect for a dataset completely in RAM (but with journaling enabled)?

Comment: Benchmarking is difficult because it's very dependent on the variables of your system: read/write mix, document size, frequency of writes, total data size, etc. The best bet is to load test using realistic data for your application.